# Android Studio Gradle Problem >> build.gradle': 1: unexpected token: < @ line 1, column 1

Tags: android, android-studio

**Could not compile build file 'E:\SwamiVivekanand\build.gradle'.**

> startup failed:
> build file 'E:\SwamiVivekanand\build.gradle': 1: **unexpected token: < @ line 1, column 1.**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  ^
  1 error
  build.gradle
```

That error Automatic comes Sometimes When Android Studio Open

Comment: How do you use to solve this problem?

Comment: copy old project to new location and open that project android existing project but today its not work

Comment: Problem is Solved thank you.

Comment: try clean and rebuild your project

Comment: I am clean all project or rebuild as well as restart android studio

Comment: Use File > Invalidate Caches / Restart > Invalidate and Restart. It should solve your problem

Comment: @bogdan i also do that step

Comment: This problem solve thank you I give that answer.

Comment: What was the final solution @Ashif ??

Comment: I delete gradle file and create new file like gradle and paste it in project location.Thank you